# Using multiple rsync jobs in applescript

Tags: applescript, rsync

Hello I want to use AppleScript to copy a file from a source Macserver to 10 other Mac servers using rsync. I have the basics working:

```
set source to "/Folder1/Folder2/"
mount volume "afp://username:password@server1/Folder1/"
set Folder1 to result as alias
set destShareName to "/Volumes/Folder1/Folder3"
do shell script "/usr/bin/rsync -rlptD --log-file=/Users/user/Documents/rsync.txt " & (quoted form of source) & " " & (quoted form of destShareName)
```

It works and I get a log of the job. I know I could copy the job and substitute server1 with server2 and run the job again. How can I create a list of servers and get the rsync job to run recusively through the list? Many thanks, John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this. You make lists and use a repeat loop. The first time through the repeat loop you grab all the first items in the lists, so make sure all the first items in each list go together. The second time through you will grab all the second items and so on. Note that all the lists should have exactly the same number of items.

```
set theServers to {"afp://username:password@server1/Folder1/", "afp://username:password@server2/Folder1/"}
set sourceFolders to {"/source1Folder/Folder2/", "/source2Folder/Folder2/"}
set destFolders to {"/dest1Folder/Folder2/", "/dest2Folder/Folder2/"}


repeat with i from 1 to count of sourceFolders
    set thisServer to item i of theServers
    set thisSource to item i of sourceFolders
    set thisDest to item i of destFolders

    mount volume thisServer
    do shell script "/usr/bin/rsync -rlptD --log-file=/Users/user/Documents/rsync.txt " & (quoted form of thisSource) & " " & (quoted form of thisDest)
end repeat
```

***EDIT***: based on your comment, if only your server changes then you could adjust your code like this...

```
set theServers to {"afp://username:password@server1/Folder1/", "afp://username:password@server2/Folder1/"}

set sourceFolder to "/source1Folder/Folder2/"
set destFolder to "/dest1Folder/Folder2/"

repeat with i from 1 to count of theServers
    mount volume (item i of theServers)
    do shell script "/usr/bin/rsync -rlptD --log-file=/Users/user/Documents/rsync.txt " & (quoted form of sourceFolder) & " " & (quoted form of destFolder)
end repeat
```

Comment: Sorry for not writing sooner, I was testing it and it all works great. It is annoying as sourceFolders & destFolders do not change (always /source1Folder/Folder2  and /dest1Folder/Folder2, respectively) yet I have to repeatedly put it in to keep the equation balanced. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad you got it working. But based on your comment I added an "EDIT" section to my post to show you an alternative that might work better for you. Good luck.

Comment: Hello @regulus6633 Yes, I figured out for myself that I need not repeatedly put in constants and my solution was very similar to yours.Thanks again, John